# How to Copy Number from One Row to Another with OrderNumber in common (DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

[image: Small snippet of a table with fields RecordSource, OrderNumber, and SerialNumber]

Trying to make a new column in this large dataset that takes the serial number from the RecordSource SO rows and applies it to SI rows containing the same order number.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a **calculated** 'Lookup' **table**:

```
Lookup = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    FILTER( 
        'Table', 
        'Table'[Source] = "SO"
    ),
    "Order", 'Table'[Order],
    "Serial", 'Table'[Serial]
)
```

2. Add the new common serial as a **calculated column** to your table:

```
Common Serial = 
LOOKUPVALUE(
    Lookup[Serial], 
    Lookup[Order], 
    'Table'[Order]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

While @Peters solution is OK, I think it is wasteful to persist a whole calculated table just for the lookup, in addition to a calculated column to access this lookup.

My suggestion is to just add this calculated column directly:

```
SerialNumberNew = 
COALESCE ( 
    'Table'[SerialNumber] , 
    CALCULATE (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[SerialNumber] ) ,
        ALLEXCEPT ( 
            'Table',
            'Table'[OrderNumber]
        ),
        'Table'[RecordSource] = "SO"
    )
)
```

You can also do this in Power Query by using a custom function to assign the `SerialNumber` using the same logic as in the above DAX code. This improves the data model slightly since there is no need for more data in the data model itself, the original `SerialNumber` column can be pruned, and there will be no additional DAX component dependencies at refresh time:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRecords({
        [RecordSource = "SI", OrderNumber = "A", SerialNumber = null],
        [RecordSource = "SO", OrderNumber = "A", SerialNumber = 123],
        [RecordSource = "SO", OrderNumber = "B", SerialNumber = 456],
        [RecordSource = "SI", OrderNumber = "B", SerialNumber = null]
    }),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"RecordSource", type text}, {"OrderNumber", type text}, {"SerialNumber", Int64.Type}}),
    Buffer = Table.Buffer(#"Changed Type"),

    SerialNumFunc = (order_num as text, buffer as table) => 
        let 
            vals = Table.SelectRows(buffer,  each ([OrderNumber] = order_num and [RecordSource] = "SO")) 
        in 
            vals{0}[SerialNumber],
            
    AddCol = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "SerialNumberNew", each [SerialNumber] ?? SerialNumFunc([OrderNumber], Buffer))
in
    AddCol
```